# Creating a Dynamic calendar in Silverlight

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight

I am attempting to create a long range calendar that dynamically loads (and unloads) event data as the user scrolls left or right through time. I'm really struggling to figure out how to lay the basic framework of the UI out and how to dynamically build the interface as the user scrolls by clicking and dragging the mouse in the view area. See the image below for a basic diagram of the intent. Each slice would have potentially multiple rectangles in it for events that occurred on that day (slice). I would like each slice to be a canvas to allow me to position those rectangles appropriately. [alt text http://www.mistertnt.com/images/DynamicCalendarDiagram.jpg](http://www.mistertnt.com/images/DynamicCalendarDiagram.jpg)

There are a few problems that I am not yet sure how to tackle but this is the first big one that I've been mulling over for a while and can't quite wrap my head around:

1. I know how to dynamically create controls but how would I go about adding things to one end of the scrollable content while removing things from the other depending on the way the user is scrolling?

Any guidance in the right direction would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Application i use the silverlight timeline control (http://timeline.codeplex.com/), a port of the SIMILE timeline widget. Very nice!

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've since moved on to a a more important project but this will come in handy if I ever need to revisit this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a name to your panel (you're perhaps using a StackPanel, I'm guessing), you could react to the events on a ScrollViewer to then add or remove items. If your bound data is an ObservableCollection, it'll likely be even easier.

However you'll almost be virtualizing the data, and it's a tricky business to be in.

Consider using the Silverlight 3 [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel(VS.95).aspx) to assist in this process.